# React Native Share not working on android intermittently

Tags: android, react-native

React Native Share not working on **android devices intermittently**.
Using version `"react-native": "~0.63.0"`

Share Method:

```
onShare = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await Share.share({
        message: "Some Text" + " " + "Play store App url link"
      });

      if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
        if (result.activityType) {
          // shared with activity type of result.activityType
        } else {
          // shared
        }
      } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
        // dismissed
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (Platform.OS === appConst.ANDROID) {
        ToastAndroid.show(appConst.ERROR_MESSAGE, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      }
      //alert(error.message);
    }
  };
```

Error I am getting on device is:

[image]

Comment: your bug is not reproduce-able. can you provide rest of the context or steps to reproduce it.

Comment: @MuhammadIqbal- This issue is not coming on android emulator. It comes on some of the actual devices and comes in like once in a five/eight times.

Comment: share actual device model for base point

Comment: @AnkitAdlakha can you verify in your actual code if it's a string that your setting in message, or the context from where you are calling is proper, ref [exception](https://github.com/dobbit/react-native/blob/94023f99ae302eeadb099f1aa218bad19668f583/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/share/ShareModule.java#L85)

Comment: @MuhammadIqbal- Actual devices on which i have tried- Samsung Galaxy A7, one plus 7.

Comment: @RohanShewale- Yes I am passing string only in message (App Name, Description and App Link)